# Select random rows such that combination of a subgroup of columns is unique

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

From `my_table` with columns `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` and `e` I want to select `N` rows randomly such that the combinations of columns `a`,`b` and `c` are unique.

I tried solving this with a group by:

```
select a, b, c, min(d), min(e) from my_table
group by a, b, c
```

This approach cannot work because it does not return actual existing rows from `my_table` since the minimum can be in different rows for the columns `d` and `e`. Furthermore `min` is not an appropriate function because it does not return random rows.

How could I achieve it?

I am working with amazon athena which is built on Presto and runs standard ANSI SQL.

Comment: What if there are less then `N` unique combinations of `a`, `b`, `c`?

Comment: Should result in an error.

Comment: That would be not that easy to achieve. Sounds more like application side logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have Presto installed, only Trino (but Athena engine v3 should be based on Trino) and in Trino you can try using `min_by`/`max_by` functions combining them with [`random`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/math.html#random) for "ordering" and some `ROW` magic:

```sql
select a, b, c, 
    min_by((d, e), random()).* as (d, e)
from my_table
group by a, b, c
```

Another approach which should work with v2 and v3 engines is using [`row_number`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#row_number) window function over partition and again use `random` for ordering:

```sql
select a, b, c, d, e 
from(
    select *,
       row_number() over(partition by a, b, c order by random()) rn
    from dataset)
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell which DBMS you are working with, so it's not possible to give a complete solution.

But the strategy would be to

1. Use *windowing functions* for grouping rows having the same a, b, c. In Oracle this would be something like ``SELECT a, b, c, (row_number() over (partition by a, b, c order by a, b, c)) id_row
2. Use another select that picks rows from the first select, using a random() function -- but you have to look at your DBMS documentation to find out which function to use